# How to get HTTP response headers after POST request in PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I want to know if it's possible to read/parse the HTTP response header after a POST request in PHP without the use of cURL..

I have PHP 5 under IIS7
The code I use to POST is :-

```
$url="http://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
        'Email' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        'Passwd' => 'xxxxxx',
        'service' => 'fusiontables',
        'source' => 'fusiontables query'
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Above, im doing a simple ClientLogin Authentication to google and I want to get the Auth token which returns in the header. Echo-ing $result only gives the body content and not headers which contains the auth token data.

Comment: don't think you can have the response headers in your example (file_get_contents will return the response body)

Comment: then what does get_headers() in php5 do? (sinan answered below) Or do you recommend any workaround for getting the auth token from Google ClienLogin using php5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function get_headers() may be the one you are looking for.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: hmm weird but now im getting: "failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?" But im not using https?!

Comment: @Power-Inside, You are probably being redirected to an SSL URL.  See the `follow_location` and `max_redirects` options in the [http context documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ignore_errors` context option ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)):

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $postdata,
        'ignore_errors' => true,
    )
);
```

Also, maybe use `fopen` rather than `file_get_contents`.  You can then call `stream_get_meta_data($fp)` to get the headers, see [Example #2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.example-fetch-ignore-redirect) on the above link.

Comment: `stream_get_meta_data` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the handy `file_get_contents` and have your headers via [$http_response_header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php).

No need for `fopen` and `stream_get_meta_data`.

`$http_response_header` will be populated with response headers right in the scope where `file_get_contents` was called.

No need even to set `ignore_errors` as only the return value of `file_get_contents` is affected by failed request, `$http_response_header` will still have your `HTTP 401`s and `500`s.

The code from the question would look like this:

```php
$url = "http://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
        'Email' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        'Passwd' => 'xxxxxx',
        'service' => 'fusiontables',
        'source' => 'fusiontables query'
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$headers = $http_response_header; // this is all you have to do!
```