# How to get header with stream?

Tags: php, http, stream, http-headers

Consider this function:

```
function use_fopen($url, $make_post_field, $headers = '') {

    $context = array(
                       'http' => array(
                       'method'  => 'POST',
                       'timeout' => '60',
                       'content' => $make_post_field)
    );
    $header = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    if (!empty($headers)) {
        foreach ($headers as $head) {
                 $header.="$head\r\n";
        }
    }

    $context['http']['header'] = $header;
    $context = stream_context_create($context);

    //$contents = @file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
    $fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);

    $stream_meta_data = @stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    print_r($stream_meta_data );
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I use the function like this:

```
$headers = array ('baz: bar');
$data = array ('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => 'baz');
$data = http_build_query($data);
print(use_fopen("http://www.example.com/phpinfo.php", $data, $headers));
```

As target url is phpinfo, I can verify that `$_POST['foo']` is set to bar and

`CONTENT_TYPE = application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

`HTTP_FOO  = baz`

So it seems context is working fine, but when I use

```
$stream_meta_data = @stream_get_meta_data($fp);
print_r($stream_meta_data );
```

I get

```
Array
(
[timed_out] => 
[blocked] => 1
[eof] => 
[wrapper_data] => Array
    (
        [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        [1] => Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2016 11:46:36 GMT
        [2] => Server: Apache
        [3] => Connection: close
        [4] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    )

[wrapper_type] => http
[stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
[mode] => r
[unread_bytes] => 8061
[seekable] => 
[uri] => http://wwwexample.com/phpinfo.php
)
```

why content-type is wrong and HTTP_FOO that is actually a header is not shown here? the change below also did not help. what should I do? to get custom headers and correct content-type?

```
$contents = @file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
print_r(get_headers($url));
```

I searched SO and found this [How to get HTTP response headers after POST request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532753/how-to-get-http-response-headers-after-post-request-in-php) but as I said I tried both `stream_get_meta_data($fp)` and `get_headers($url)` but I don't get my custom headers. what else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Found your thread from google as I had the same problem as you. I solved it with the function [stream_context_set_default](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php). Thought I'd post it for the next one stumbling in from google, or if you still need a solution.